# Confirm before a form submit

Tags: php, javascript

I have searched for an answer but couldn't find one!

I have a simple form,

```
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="completeYes" value="Complete Transaction" />
</form>
```

How would I adjust this to confirm before processing the form?

I tried onclick, but couldn't get it working.

Any ideas?

UPDATE - What I now have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('myCoolForm');

el.addEventListener('submit', function(){
return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');
}, false);
</script>

<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST" id="myCoolForm">
     <input type="submit" name="completeYes" value="Complete Transaction" />
</form>
```

Comment: what was the onclick code that you had?

Comment: You have to add the listener **after** the form is in the document. Use window.onload to add it, or put the script after the form in the page.

Comment: Wasn't aware it had to come afterwards, but it makes sense. Thanks RobG.

Comment: [javascript form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6515502/6521116)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Form Submit - Confirm or Cancel Submission Dialog Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST" id="myCoolForm">
    <input type="submit" name="completeYes" value="Complete Transaction" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myCoolForm');

el.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');
}, false);
```

Edit: you can always use inline JS code like this:

```
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');">
    <input type="submit" name="completeYes" value="Complete Transaction" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening when I click the button? Just going to the adminprocess.php page!

Comment: Did you use markup I provided? Your HTML doesn't contain the id element I added to the form so I can grab it via `getElementById` method.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code and it's just bypassing the confirmation attempt. I'll update the question with what I now have.

Comment: When I tried this if press "cancel" it still submits the form. Shouldn't it prevent the form from submitting too?

Comment: you must change the onsubmit into onclick

Comment: add  event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 20):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');">
```

Comment: @RobG you're mistaking a bit. This `<form> <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');"> </form>` works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

The correct event is onSubmit() and it should be attached to the form. Although I think it's possible to use onClick, but onSubmit is the correct one.

Comment: There is not onsubmit event. There is an HTML attribute is named *onsubmit*, but the related event is the [submit](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) event.

Comment: ok, this is about semantics, as onclick is not event as well, but I agree with you, as you are indicating the correct terms

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery.. you can use an event handler to trigger before submission

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#formID").submit(function(){
      // handle submission
   });
});
```

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Not using jQuery, but thankyou for the suggestion. Definitely something I need to learn more about.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using jQuery if you are going to be developing with javascript. It provides a platform on which many functions you may have to create yourself, are already created. And its very extendable.

Comment: Any suggestions on the best place to get to grips with it? Quite simply the jQuery website?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var submit = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
  
/* set onclick on submit input */   
submit.setAttribute("onclick", "return test()");

//submit.addEventListener("click", test);

function test() {

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?')) {         
    return true;         
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="admin.php" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have a form ID and couldn't add inline in the `form` tag. I ended up with the following jQuery code

```
    var form = $("form").first();
    form.on('submit', function() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myCoolForm").addEventListener('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
           
            var message = "Are you sure you want to perform this action?";
            
             if (confirm(message)) {
                    document.getElementById('myCoolForm').submit();
                    return true;
             }
             return false;
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

if you have more then one submit buttons that do different actions you can do it this way.

```
<input TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="submitDelete"  VALUE="Delete Script" onclick='return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");'>
```