# Javascript confirm box inside PHP Echo function

Tags: javascript, php, echo, confirm

I have a link inside PHP Echo function called "Delete". When user clicks on it, the delete.php page is called and the selected book is deleted from the database. So, I would like to insert a confirmation box  asking user if he is sure to delete the book but I don't know how to do it.

This is the code:

```
echo "<td><a class = 'echo_link' href='delete-book.php?ID={$Book->ID}'> Delete </a></td> \n";
```

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9139075/1129785

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
echo "<td>
<a class = 'echo_link' href='#' onclick='if(confirm(\"message\")) location.href=\"delete-book.php?ID={$Book->ID}\";'> Delete </a>
</td> \n";
```

Answer (score 3):

it works perfectly....

```
 <a  href='http://www.google.com' onclick="return confirm('Are U sure?');"> Delete </a>
```

Comment: This code will give the error due to your quotation marks

Comment: @user3156271 this code will give the error check the code and try it. this has the error.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
echo "<td><a class = 'echo_link' href='delete-book.php?ID=5' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete?\")'> Delete </a></td> \n";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code

```
<?php $bookid =  $Book->ID; ?>
<td>
<a class = 'echo_link' href='<?php echo "delete-book.php?ID=$bookid"; ?>'  onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?");'> Delete </a>
</td> 
<?php echo"\n";
?>
```

Comment: This code will give not echo the `$Book->ID` which is not correct.

Comment: you can try my code now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way. It's may helps you.

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

You can take a look at this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dq6W6/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
echo "<td><a class = 'echo_link' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?');' href='delete-book.php?ID={$Book->ID}'> Delete </a></td> \n";
```

Comment: -1, data-confirm? is that standard html? I do not think so.

Comment: AFAIK, HTML (at least HTML5) allows any `data-` attribute.

Comment: Only html5. And REMEMBER that html5 is not yet a standard -.-