# Confirmation Before Delete

Tags: php, function, confirmation

I want to confirm from user before delete an entry

I am calling the delete function on click as

```
<li><img src="delete1.png" onClick="delete_records();" alt="delete_records" /></li>
```

the funcion is saved in a .js file as

```
function delete_records() 
{
document.frm.action = "delete.php";
document.frm.submit();
}
```

The delete.php is as follows

```
<?php require 'connections/connections.php';  ?>
<?php require 'includes/higherauth.php';// for user access level check  
?>

<?php 
// To stop accessing the page without login

if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
}else{
header('Location: logIn.php');
}
?>
<?php

error_reporting(0); 
$rado = $_POST['rado'];
$chkcount = count($rado);

if(!isset($rado))
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('At least one checkbox Must be Selected !!!');
    window.location.href = 'account.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++)
    {

        $del = $rado[$i];
        $sql=$con->query("DELETE FROM mntr WHERE id=".$del);
    }   

    if($sql)
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('<?php echo $chkcount; ?> Records Was Deleted !!!');
        window.location.href='account.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('Error while Deleting , TRY AGAIN');
        window.location.href='account.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }   
}
?>
```

Please help me to add a warning for confirming the delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a confirm message before delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139075/how-to-show-a-confirm-message-before-delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is add a confirm and test the response

```
function delete_records() 
{
    var conf= confirm("Do you really want delete?");
    if (conf== true){
       document.frm.action = "delete.php";
       document.frm.submit();
    }else{
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have two user access levels, how could i check the same also before deleting a row with a _SESSION variable       if($_SESSION["UserLevel"]=='2'){
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('You are not Authorised to delete !!!');
  window.location.href = 'account.php';
  </script>
        <?php

 }