# can anybody tell me how to use sweet alert before deleting a record from database in JSP.?

Tags: jsp, sweetalert

I want sweet alert before deleting a record from database in jsp. Please help. I have already tried the codes from codepen and other sources, but it doesn't work. Any help with a proper code will be appreciated. I am using it with a  anchor tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139075/how-to-show-a-confirm-message-before-delete ?