# Javascript alert message on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and I have trouble finding a solution that works for what I need.
I have a form and when the user submits the form, if a checkbox is checked, it needs to display an alert message.

```
<form method="post" action="inserting.php" id="form1" class="signupform">
  <input type="hidden" name="allowlang" id="allowlang" value="no" />

  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:left;">

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="enable" id="enable" value="YES" style="width:15px !important"/>
        &nbsp;
        There has been an issue.</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
<br />

  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:left;">

    <tr>
      <td height="50"></td>
      <td> <br /><button id="registerButton" type="submit" style="float:left;">Send Data</button></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>
```

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box

Comment: You should edit your post to show some javascript you tried so we can help you on a base you know. check the link added by @Ashish too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the start of yout form to this

```
<form method="post" action="inserting.php" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="signupform" name="signupform">
```

Use this Jscript

```
function validateForm() {
    if (document.forms["signupform"]["enable"].checked)
        alert("yes, there has been an issue");
}
```

You do not jQuery for this.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TBs8x/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try in jquery

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
  if ($('#enable').is(':checked')) {  //if checkbox is checked
    alert("checked");
  }
  else {
    return false;
  } 
})
```

methods to be learned:

1. [**`submit()`**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
2. [**`is()`**](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `button type="submit"` to `button`.

 Submit the form using `submit()` function.

```
$( "#buttonId" ).click(function() {
 //CHECK here for the checkbox;
if(checked) alert();
 $( "#form" ).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ordinary button that calls a function that shows the alert, and then if necessary, submits the form by calling formObject.submit().