# How to display a warning message before deleting a file after clicking a submit button with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form which shows a file in server and gives me option to handle it like rename, delete, etc.

Here the code:

```
if ($handle = opendir('./uploads')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $file = substr($file, 0, -4);

        echo '<form action="w03handling.php" method="POST">';
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$file'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='new_name' value='$file'>";
            echo '<input type="image" name="calc" src="img/ok.png" alt="Calculate" title="Calculate">';
            echo '<input type="image" name="rename" src="img/edit.png" alt="Rename" title="Rename">';
            echo '<input type="image" name="subst" src="img/change.png" alt="Upload new file" title="Upload new file">';
            echo '<input type="image" name="del" src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete">';
        echo '</form>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

It reads all files in one folder, list them all in the screen with the respective handling possibilities.

I would like to display a message when I click on DELETE which asks the user if he really wants to delete the file.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need JavaScript for this. Look into [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)

Comment: this problem is also covered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, as @JohnConde suggested.  PHP should only be the backend and only runs on the server side.  To interact with the client, you need to use client side languages: HTML, Javascript, etc.

Comment: @Devon [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23016805/) shows that it is possible to solve it using only PHP or at least without javascript, etc.

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil that isn't PHP.  That is Javascript in HTML echoed by PHP.  PHP itself isn't doing anything but echoing.

Comment: You're right @Devon. But to say that this has nothing to do with PHP is anyway too much. We need at least PHP to echo this... ;-). And of course we could do it without PHP! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('./uploads')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $file = substr($file, 0, -4);

        echo '<form action="w03handling.php" method="POST">';
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$file'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='new_name' value='$file'>";
        echo '<input type="image" name="calc" src="img/ok.png" alt="Calculate" title="Calculate">';
        echo '<input type="image" name="rename" src="img/edit.png" alt="Rename" title="Rename">';
        echo '<input type="image" name="subst" src="img/change.png" alt="Upload new file" title="Upload new file">';
        echo '<input type="image" name="del" src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure to delete this file");\'>';
        echo '</form>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @chung ! That was fast and clean! ;-) It works just out of the box!

Comment: @Fred -ii-  Thanks as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmdeletion() {

var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if (r == true)
  {
     // code that deletes all
  }
else // else part could be removed if not required
  {
     // do nothing or handle cancel
  }

}
</script>
```

and use your php code as :

```
echo '<input onClick="confirmdeletion()" type="image" name="del" src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete">';
```

OR just use:

```
echo '<input onClick="confirm(\'Are you Sure you want to delete?\')" type="image" name="del" src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete">';
```

Comment: [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23016805/) works better because it won't try and redirect after clicking on cancel. Yours works, but it wants to redirect on cancel.

Comment: You can remove the else part if you do not want to redirect @Fred-ii-

Comment: You could make a note of it in your answer then ;-) Just so the OP knows and is aware of it. You know and I know, but will the OP know? *ah* ;-) the $64,000 question.

Comment: sure @Fred-ii-. Thats a good idea! and Thanks! made the changes

Comment: I re-tested your code with OP's PHP, still the same thing (even by getting rid of the `else{}`). What did work (*or could work*) however is adding a return by changing `echo '<input onClick="confirmdeletion()"` to `echo '<input onClick="return confirmdeletion()"`