# How should I use a window.confirm dialog box with a form?

Tags: javascript

I have tried window.confirm on a submit button saying "Are you sure" but even if I click on no it submits itself? Is this the wrong way of using it?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.confirm('Are you sure you want to transfer to user?')">
Transfer
</button>
```

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box

Comment: First of all you will need to show your code. Second, learn what `confirm` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to transfer to user?')">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) returns a boolean. To make it work you will need to add `return` in the front:

```
return confirm(...);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fu5LuLmx/

Instead of attaching to the `click` event, you might also want to consider attaching it to the `submit` event of the form, such that this piece of code would execute whenever the form is being submitted, not only when clicking this button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent from submitting so remove the `onclick` event, and add a `onsubmit` event on the form

```
<form name="form" id="myForm" onsubmit="return ask();">

<script>
function ask() {
    if  (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to transfer to user?')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Won't do anything because you don't return the function's return value in the onsubmit handler.