# Manipulate webpage based on user selection of popup window in asp.net website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net website. I want to open a popup asking for user confirmation in code behind page.

I have a drop down with some values. "cancel ticket" is one of those values. So when user selects this item, I want to display a confirmation box asking user "Are you sure you want to cancel the ticket"?

I've tried some code using JavaScript,

HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" onchange ="GetSelectedItem(this);" />
```

JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedItem(x) {
        if (x.value == 4) {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel support ticket ?");
        }
    }
```

which is displaying a popup as I want.

Now, I want to make a textbox and a label visible if user clicked on "OK" and reset dropdownlist if user clicked on "Cancel"

Comment: Move this logic on the client side, with a confirm dialog, using javascript.

Comment: The "code-behind" C# code...end-intention is to create html/javascript to be sent to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this, i hop this help you

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Try not to post link-only answers. While they may be correct, the integrity of your answer will be compromised should the link ever change/close. Try to include the essential parts from this link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would use

ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The right way to approach this is by checking the value and prompting the user in the client side via javascript ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box) will probably help you).

But if you insist on going through the server, you can either:

- Do an ajax call and then prompt the user for confirmation,
- or create another form/view to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a bootstrap modal  and injecting script like `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock (Type, String,"$(modal).modal('show')")`

Do remember to add the bootstrap js and css

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

1- Create a invisible div with your cancel button (and/or others elements/controls you want)

```
<div id="div_dialog" style="display: none;" >
    <h3>Do you want to cancel?</h3>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  onclick="Button1_Click"/>
</div>
```

2- Use jquery to use your drop down as a trigger and dialog your hidden div

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // this will open the popup when drop donw change 
      //(aply your filter by selected item)
        $("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            $("#div_dialog").dialog({
                dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
                height: 160,
                width: 220,
                title: "My modal Dialog Popup",               
                modal: true
            });
            return false;
        });
        // this function will do the postback and fire the event in the popup button
       $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(
         function() {
            <%=this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this.Button1))%>;
       });
    });

</script>
```

3- Instead of using `ddlStatus_Tickets_SelectedIndexChanged` event, handle your confirmation code in the confirmation button event click

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you code
    }
```