# Need to display an alert when hitting submit via radio choices

Tags: javascript, html

edit: I don't think the similar question mentinoed in the comments can help :(. Unless I'm just really bad at this... I can get a simple alert message to come up but can't get the alert for the the individual radio button to show.

I'm just doing a simple form with radio buttons with Javascript to give an alert after hitting submit when one of the choices is chosen. I'm brand new to Javascript so I'm not sure what else I can do...

The HTML works but the function inside of it doesn't at all. I'm lost on what else to do. Any advice would be really appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Gender Check </title>
    <meta charset ="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <form id= "form" name ="form" onsubmite="gender()">

        <label>Male
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="male"/>
        </label>

        <label>Female
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="female"/>
        </label>

        <label>Trans
        <input type="radio" id="trans" name="trans"/>
        </label>

        <label>Alien
        <input type="radio" id="alien" name="alien"/>
        </label>

        <label>Boeing AH-64 Apache Attack Helicopter
        <input type="radio" id="helicopter" name="helicopter"/>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Don't lie to me."/>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function gender() {
    var male=document.form[0].element[0];
    var female=document.form[0].element[1];
    var trans=document.form[0].element[2];
    var alien=document.form[0].element[3];
    var helicopter=document.form[0].element[4];

    if (document.getElementById('male').checked == true)
    {
    alert("You are a Male.")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('female').checked == true)
    {
    alert("You are a Feale.")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('trans').checked == true)
    {
    alert("You are Trans.")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('alien').checked == true)
    {
    alert("You are an...uh...Alien?")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('helicopter').checked == true)
    {
    alert("You are definitely not a four-blade, twin-turboshaft attack helicopter with a tailwheel-type landing gear arrangement and a tandem cockpit for a two-man crew.")
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Please pick a choice")
    }

}
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = gender;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Form Submit - Confirm or Cancel Submission Dialog Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box)

Comment: This form is glorious... +1.

Comment: awww such a cute code. You'll get there eventually. Keep it up :)

Comment: I love the apache-helicopter part. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors were :

1. You used `document.form[0].element[1]` instead of `document.form[1]`
2. You wrote `onsubmite` instead of `onsubmit`
3. All your radio input had the same `name` attribute thus you were able to select multiple choices. You should use the same name for each radio button of the same group
4. You can reduce `male.checked == true` with `male.checked` alone

```js
function gender() {
      
      var male = document.form[0];
      var female = document.form[1];
      var trans = document.form[2];
      var alien = document.form[3];
      var helicopter = document.form[4];

      if (male.checked) {
        alert("You are a Male.")
      } else if (female.checked) {
        alert("You are a Female.")
      } else if (trans.checked) {
        alert("You are Trans.")
      } else if (alien.checked) {
        alert("You are an...uh...Alien?")
      } else if (helicopter.checked) {
        alert("You are definitely not a four-blade, twin-turboshaft attack helicopter with a tailwheel-type landing gear arrangement and a tandem cockpit for a two-man crew.")
      } else {
        alert("Please pick a choice")
      }

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gender Check</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form" name="form" onsubmit="gender()">

    <label>Male
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="choice" />
    </label>

    <label>Female
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="choice" />
    </label>

    <label>Trans
      <input type="radio" id="trans" name="choice" />
    </label>

    <label>Alien
      <input type="radio" id="alien" name="choice" />
    </label>

    <label>Boeing AH-64 Apache Attack Helicopter
      <input type="radio" id="helicopter" name="choice" />
    </label>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Don't lie to me." />

  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE**

Instead of `document.form[0];` (first element of the form) you can use `document.form.choice[0]` which will look for the list of radio and select the first one `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form id= "form" name ="form" onsubmit="gender()">
```

You need to associate an event known as `onsubmit` which will call `gender()` function when form is submitted.

You can prevent the submission by returning false via function and for that you will need to do something like this

```
onsubmit="return gender()"
```

If you want to submit form, change the button type to `button` and associate an event as `onclick='gender()'` and keep rest of the code unchanged.

Comment: what kind of sense does your comment make? @shanks

Comment: Is there anything else I might be missing? I used your suggestions but still getting no alert box. Should I choose a different way to go about doing this? @Danyal