# Why is my form submitted after cancelling the confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Here is my sample code:

```
<button onClick="CheckData()" type="submit">
```

I have some conditions in CheckData function:

```
if (5<6) {
   warning = "sure?";
} else if (5>3) {
   warning = "really?";
} else {
  warning = '';
}
```

Then I check:

```
if (warning.length>0) {
   return confirm(warning);
} else {
   return true; //also tried false
}
```

So I need the confirm dialog for the first two conditions, otherwise, I don't want the dialog to be displayed.

Now, when one of the first two conditions are met, the confirm dialog pops up, but when I click on cancel, it still submits the form.

Any suggestions?

PS: This code is a demo and different from the real one. But the concept is the same.

Comment: Where are you reading the value returned by confirm()?

Comment: `if (waning.length>0) {` you have a typo in `warning`.

Comment: Well you do not have a return in the inline event listener and you have a bug with a typo

Comment: ignore typo, everything is perfect in real project code

Comment: onClick="return CheckData()"  <--- too lazy to find a dupe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Form Submit - Confirm or Cancel Submission Dialog Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515502/javascript-form-submit-confirm-or-cancel-submission-dialog-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the `event` Object to the `CheckData` function and prevent the default action if the confirm returns false with `event.preventDefault()`.

```html
<form>
<button onClick="CheckData(event)" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
function CheckData(e){
 var warning;
 if (5<6) {
   warning = "sure?";
} else if (5>3) {
   warning = "really?";
} else {
  warning = '';
}
if (warning.length>0) {
   var con = confirm(warning);
   if(con){
   return true;
   } else {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
   }
} else {
   return true; 
}
}
</script>
```

You can also `return` the result of `CheckData` so the default action will be prevented if it returns false.

```html
<form>
<button onClick="return CheckData()" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
function CheckData(){
 var warning;
 if (5<6) {
   warning = "sure?";
} else if (5>3) {
   warning = "really?";
} else {
  warning = '';
}
if (warning.length>0) {
   var con = confirm(warning);
   return con;
} else {
   return true; 
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: @LashaPalelashvili No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<form onsubmit="return CheckData()">
    <button type="submit" />
    ...
</form>
```

Explanation:

- The [onsubmit](https://javascript.info/forms-submit) event handler is called when the form is submitted.
- When the event handler returns `false` the submission is aborted.