# HTML form submit show javascript confirm window

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="addticketupdate.php">
....

</form>
```

Then above the form I have:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
... do stuff here
}
?>
```

So the submit button in my form has an id and name of *"submit"*

I want to make a JavaScript confirm box popup when the submit button is clicked, the statement says: If user clicks "OK" the php code excuted, else do nothing.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confirm before a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493009/confirm-before-a-form-submit)

Comment: @Mat It does :) It's "Elegant Slang", I got vaild result in google translate.

Comment: @Mat it doesn't really matters, I didn't actually edited the meanning, only got the word shorter. I can't see in it any kind of foolishness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply use this:**

```
<form method="post" action="addticketupdate.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you want to submit the form?');" >
```

**Option 2:** (On submit button click)

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var res = confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
    if(!res){ 
       return false; 
    }else{ 
       //submits form 
    }
});
```

Comment: just tried your option 2 and it used the <?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { ... } code

Answer (score 1):

You can do as,

```
<form method="post" action="addticketupdate.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Need to submit??');">
<!-- your other html input code -->
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function validate() {
    var result = confirm("Do you want to submit!");
    return result;
}
</script>
<form name="form-name" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be making using dialog box instead alert popup box.
However dialog don't have full support so "Fancy Box" is the best in this case.

[FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

So after installizing fancy box into your website you should remove the default button they have there and change it to input type submit and add name it as "submit".